# Generate an exception or use instanceof in an if

Tags: java, performance, exception

Sometimes, to avoid using `if` I create code that throws exception to parse some values.

For example: When you have an input field where you can write a partner number or a partner name to search, I do like:

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(string);
    // use the input as int
} catch (NumberFormatException) {
    // use the input as a String
}
```

Now I have a similar problem, but with `InputStream`.

```
InputStream is;
try {
    is = (FileInputStream) fileItem.getInputStream();
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    is = (ByteArrayInputStream) fileItem.getInputStream();
}
```

My question is: Is better do it in that way throwing the `exception` or maybe an if with `instanceof` like:

```
InputStream is;
if (fileItem.getInputStream() instanceof FileInputStream) {
    is = (FileInputStream) fileItem.getInputStream();
} else if (fileItem.getInputStream() instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
    is = (ByteArrayInputStream) fileItem.getInputStream();
}
```

And ***WHY***?

I've found similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306827/which-is-better-more-efficient-check-for-bad-values-or-catch-exceptions-in-java) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085502/which-is-better-integer-parseint-and-catch-exception-or-verify-string-with-p) but there are not exact

Comment: `instanceof` is the better way

Comment: You may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control

Comment: Why test at all?   If `is` is in both cases downcastable to an `InputStream` then just write `InputStream is = fileItem.getInputStream()`

Comment: Both seems like a code smell to me, if you care about the specific concrete type - you should carry it all the way.

Comment: I'm reopening as a this is not a "simple control flow", the usage of  `instanceof` as the suggested alternative has much more flaws (and thus depth to the question) than a simple "control flow" alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more general rule for exception would be to avoid them if they can also be expressed by a more simple construct like an if.

generating an exception is expensive! it needs to collect the call stack - and depending on you application complexity - this alone can be a horrible source of garbage on your heap, which needs to be cleaned up by the GC.

Comment: When deciding whether to use exceptions or other control flow constructs, I don't think that size of call stack, heap memory and GC performance should be the primary concerns.

Answer (score 1):

In *general*, prefer RTTI (i.e. `instanceof`) over exception handling.

However in this case your test is completely unnecessary.  Since it appears you only want an `InputStream` and don't actually care which specific type it is, just write:

```
InputStream is = fileItem.getInputStream();
```

You only need to specialise to one of the derived subclasses of `InputStream` if you wish to invoke special methods that don't exist in the base class.